# cakephp how can I read data from a xml webservice?

Tags: xml, web-services, cakephp

what do I need to do to receive date from this xml service:
http://www.OpenLigaDB.de/Webservices/Sportsdata.asmx?WSDL?

Does anyone know a good tutorial how to get the data from a xml webservice?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```php
function xml() {

  // import XML class 
  App::import('Xml'); 

  // your XML file's location or however you want to get it
  $file = "my_xml_file.xml"; 

  // now parse it 
  $parsed_xml =& new XML($file); 
  $parsed_xml = Set::reverse($parsed_xml);

  // see the returned array 
  debug($parsed_xml); 
}
```

Then access it via a multidimensional array. Voila!